# Resolve functions on routes or states without templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Traditionally, route providers in angular map routes to URL template paths and controllers:

```
$route.when(
"/friends/:friendID",
{
    templateUrl: "views/friend-detail.htm"
}
);
```

Instead, I'd like to map them to render functions that are defined on a single controller and are applied to a single view. The essence of what I want to do is captured in the strategy outlined [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-mapping-angularjs-routes-onto-url-parameters-and-client-side-events.htm), which boils down to doing:

```
$route.when(
"/friends/:friendID",
{
    event: "friends.view"
}
);
```

I have two questions about implementing this strategy:

First, would it be possible to implement this strategy using `ui-router` rather than `ng-route`? Assuming it would be possible, how would the implementation need to change to map events to states rather than routes?

Second, when implementing this strategy (using either `ui-router` or `ng-route`), **is it possible to put `resolve` functions on states/routes that inject dependencies into my *existing* controller before it executes the specified render method?**  (I know in `ui-router` controllers are only initialized if a template is inflated - does this mean that `resolve` functions are ignored as well, and is the corollary true in `ng-route`?